# Change background on button click

Tags: android, xml

I have a button that i want to become red when clicked(not permanently, just to show that it's been clicked) right now i am doing so with a setVisibility and i have an imageView on top of it with the changed color, but now i want to improve my code and do it with a separate button_red.xml file, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:background="@drawable/img_red" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:background="@drawable/img_btn_bkg"/>
</selector>
```

now, when i set the background of the imageButton to button_red.xml i get a failed to parse error, why?

I have the same thing done in another application and it works (except i had androdi:src changing) did i forget something?, i have all the drawables inside drawable-nodpi and the button_red.xml in drawable folder

Things i've done: copied the xml from another project, changed src to background, changed the drawables, and changed the background in my imageButton to the xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `android:background` to `android:drawable` in your selector. Then just set this selector for whatever attribute (src, background, etc.), such as `android:background="@drawable/button_red"`.

Comment: It works now, thanks :) now i see that i had drawable in my other app too, i don't know why i changed it..

Answer (score 0):

Do you get still errors when you add `android:state_pressed="false"` into the 2nd item?

Comment: yes i still get the error, the xml file is the same i have in my other project, so it's strange that it doesn't work, i tried changing the src  intead  of the background but i still get the same error

Comment: Failed to parse file "here directory to the file"
Exception details are logged into window > show view > error log